# How to setup WebStorm to use PostCSS/Tailwind

Tags: webstorm, tailwind-css, postcss

I have the latest WebStorm 2020.3. It supports Tailwind CSS, I installed the PostCSS plugin and used NPM to install Tailwind CSS and all sorts of plugins.

What I have no clue about is how to setup WebStorm to actually use PostCSS with a file watcher to actually run and do anything useful. I asked JetBrains and they had no actual useful information.

All I need is some simple example of how to get WebStorm to use Tailwind.

Comment: what problems setting up the file watcher have you faced? what command(s) do you run in terminal to transpile your files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial project setup doesn't depend on an IDE. For the quick start, documentation on the Tailwind CSS site should be helpful.

`Tailwind CSS` plugin in WebStorm 2020.3 adds convenient features like Tailwind CSS classes completion and CSS preview. It doesn't require any configuration, it will just work as soon as you have `node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css` and `node_modules/.bin/tailwind` local files.

If you use tailwndcss version 2.x then make sure you also have dependencies on `postcss` and `autoprefixer` in your `package.json`, as written in https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2#install-tailwind-css-v2-0-and-post-css-8

Basic setup doesn't require to configure any File Watcher.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a setting I had forgot and stumbled on this post.

If you want PHPStorm to understand PostCSS in your CSS file's all you need to do is go to `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Stylesheets -> Dialects`. There you will set your *Project CSS Dialect* to **PostCSS** .